# Web API 2 DELETE method always returns 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, iis-express, http-delete

I have a an action on my `Email` Web API 2 controller:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Email")]
public class EmailController : ApiController {

    //...

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("Remove/{id}")]
    private void Remove(int id) {
        _repo.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

When I call the action from Fiddler with `DELETE` `http://localhost:35191/api/Email/Remove/35571` (or by any other method) I get a `500` back with the generic IIS error page that gives me no information on the error.

It seems the error is occurring before my action is ever called because setting a breakpoint within the action results in the breakpoint never being hit.

Is there some sort of configuration required to allow `DELETE` methods in IIS (Express)?

I've tried explicitly allowing `DELETE` in my web.config:

```
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a SyntaxView installed in Fiddler (it holds a bit more details about the error usually)?

Comment: Show your routing. Do you have a `[RoutePrefix(...)]` attribute on the `ApiController`? Is it `api/Email`? Furthermore, both your controller class and your action method must be `public` I believe.

Comment: SyntaxView only gives me a syntax-highlighted version of the HTML page IIS gives me.

Comment: why is your method private?

Comment: @Jonesy, Wow......  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Glad it was an easy fix.  Must be a case of the Mondays.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to make your exposed methods `public`:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("Remove/{id}")]
public void Remove(int id) {
    _repo.Remove(id);
}
```

If that didn't work then you probally need to remove the WebDav(web.config):

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
   </modules>
   <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you.

Comment: adding remove WebDAV fixed it. Route had no affect.

Comment: by removing webdav I understand it fixed the problem but what else did it remove?